# What is most reliable and up to date Java/Android SDK for foursquare?

Tags: java, android, sdk, foursquare

What is most reliable and up to date Java/Android SDK for foursquare that covers api v2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have only 1.0 version of their API so far.

https://code.google.com/p/foursquare-api-java/